# Linking a C++ project in Code::Blocks to SQLite

Tags: c++, sqlite, codeblocks

I have a problem with linking SQLite to my C::B project as I'm complete newbie. I downloaded sqlite-shell and sqlite-dll [from this site](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html). But there is 
nothing I can link(as far as I know)!

Can you please tell me what should I do? Maybe I should download something else?

I searched through the internet and people had such files as **libsqlite3.a**. How can I get them and link them?

I also tried downloading sqlite-amalgamation and compiling my library but it didn't work! (It wanted a host application...

Please help me guys! Give me a clue!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As you seem to have little experience with linking dll libraries, the amalgamation is probably the right thing for you to use. What specific errors were you running into while trying to compile it? You mentioned that you want a host application. What do you mean by that? Please be aware that unlike most other SQL implementations, SQLite does not use a client/server model. Databases are simply files on disk that are read directly by your application, without a database server application in between.

Comment: You probably downloaded the wrong file (I suspect something like the 'Precompiled Binaries for Windows'). What you need to link against SQLite is an installation from source files which you'll need to configure and build on your development machine. Check [this download](http://www.sqlite.org/2014/sqlite-autoconf-3080500.tar.gz) please, and follow the installation instructions.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ

I have (very) stupid question.

I have to do this: `cd' to the directory containing the package's source code and type ` `./configure' to configure the package for your system.`

Soo I go to CMD <C:/SQLite>: (where I have unpacked all the files you wanted me to download) but where do I use './configure' command?

Comment: @Veeper Do you have MinGW installed on your environment, and use the Msys `bash` to execute `./configure`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you sooo much! :) I installed Msys and it worked!
ComicSansMS Thank you too for your help.

Thank u both guys once again ^^